# TypeScript - Union type not working function return

Tags: typescript

I have an interface an enum and a type :

```
export interface Filters {
  cat: Array<string>;
  statuses: Array<Status | TopStatus>;
}

export enum Status {
  ARCHIVED,
  IN_PROGRESS,
  COMING
}

export type TopStatus = Status.ARCHIVED | Status.IN_PROGRESS;
```

And in the method:

```
  handleStatuses(myFilters: Filters): Array<string | TopStatus> {
    return [...myFilters.cat, ...myFilters.statuses];
  }
```

I have the error `2322` who says he's waiting `string | ARCHIVED | IN_PROGRESS | COMING` while the method returns `string ARCHIVED | IN_PROGRESS`

But it works when the method returns to Array  `

Comment: I think there might be several things here, but `...myFilters.statuses` should be of type `Array<Status | TopStatus>`, but in the function you expect it only to return the `TopStatus` bit, without handling that in the function body. You might get away with casting the types `return [...myFilters.cat, ...myFilters.statuses] as [string[], TopStatus[]]`, but then your method will be prone to an error that the compiler can no longer warn you about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spreading `myFilters.statuses` will cause spreading `Array<Status | TopStatus>`, so the value that you return from this function will return type `Array<string | Status | TopStatus>` instead of manually declared `Array<string | TopStatus>`. This is clearly and absolutely right, everything is working as designed :)

If you are sure, that `myFilters.statuses` inside of your function is only includes `TopFilter`, you can force retyping:

```js
handleStatuses(myFilters: Filters): Array<string | TopStatus> {
    return [...myFilters.cat, ...(myFilters.statuses as Array<TopStatus>)];
}
```

or redeclare the return type of the function in correct way:

```js
handleStatuses(myFilters: Filters): Array<string | Status | TopStatus> {
    return [...myFilters.cat, ...myFilters.statuses];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Running that [code in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20Filters%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20cat%3A%20Array%3Cstring%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20statuses%3A%20Array%3CStatus%20%7C%20TopStatus%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20enum%20Status%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20ARCHIVED%2C%0D%0A%20%20IN_PROGRESS%2C%0D%0A%20%20COMING%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20TopStatus%20%3D%20Status.ARCHIVED%20%7C%20Status.IN_PROGRESS%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20handleStatuses(myFilters%3A%20Filters)%3A%20Array%3Cstring%20%7C%20TopStatus%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B...myFilters.cat%2C%20...myFilters.statuses%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) gives:

```
Type '(string | Status)[]' is not assignable to type '(string | Status.ARCHIVED | Status.IN_PROGRESS)[]'.
  Type 'string | Status' is not assignable to type 'string | Status.ARCHIVED | Status.IN_PROGRESS'.
    Type 'Status.COMING' is not assignable to type 'string | Status.ARCHIVED | Status.IN_PROGRESS'.
```

Specifically:

> Type 'Status.COMING' is not assignable to type 'string | Status.ARCHIVED | Status.IN_PROGRESS'.

You're trying to assign an enum to a type that only accepts a subset of its values.